# Single or multiple key-value pair data structure for vector search with Marqo?

Tags: machine-learning, vector-search, marqo

I'm implementing vector search for a work project using Marqo Cloud. I have some data for my documents (products) that can either be structured as:

A single key-value pair, for example: Tags: red, spotty, nylon, casual

Or multiple key-value pairs with each tag title, for example:
Color: red
Design: spotty
Material: nylon
Style: casual

Will one of these data structures perform better than the other in vector search? Or is the difference likely to be negligible?

Answer (score 0):

If these are all tensor fields (used during vector search) here are some things to be aware of.

- The single k-v pair will only work if the value is a string. List of strings are only supported as non-tensor fields used for filtering. So this would work: **`Tags: "blue, patterned, cotton, elegant"`**
- Because there is only one k-v pair, only a single tensor field is generated. Because the string is short, you will likely only get a single vector for this tensor field
- For the multiple k-v pair case, each k-v pair will generate a tensor field (and 1 vector per tensor field).
- The extra vectors will require greater RAM usage, and perhaps, depending on the scale of your index, a slightly slower search speed

Vector search performs better when the model that is creating the embedding has some context. So an embedding generated from the string **`"blue, patterned, cotton, elegant"`** will likely have better recall performance than 4 separate embeddings that are each generated from a single word. So for recall, speed and resource performance the first option will work better in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

What crabdog says is good, reading should be fast and avoid minimal resource consumption.

I don't know exactly how your project is structured, but remember that you can use data cachers, queues and other techniques to mi